# Are there any services to search for photographs of a specific location or building?

Tags: geotagging, locations, search

I'm trying to find pictures of the building that used to house my local library. We're celebrating the 25th anniversary of our move to a new facility, and the building still exists (not sure what it is used for now). I can find it in Google Streetview, but it would be nice if I could locate some higher resolution shots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flickr has quite a good map feature for photos that have geo-tagging info:

http://www.flickr.com/map/

Comment: This is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. Sadly no pictures of the building.

Answer (score 2):

[Panoramio](http://www.panoramio.com)

You either enter a name (ex: 'statue of liberty') or use the interactive map.

Some of the same images are available in [Google Maps](http://maps.google.com). You only need to go to where you want and enable the 'Photos' option from the overview thumbnail on the upper right of the map.

Comment: If I could mark 2 answers correct I'd mark yours as well as ltn100's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could try **Google search by image**. It allows you to upload an image and Google will try to find similar images of it. You can find a detailed explanation with instructions [here](http://www.google.com/insidesearch/searchbyimage.html).